# SQL Plus: how to change directory and show current working directory

Tags: windows, oracle, sqlplus

I just installed Oracle, and I am working with SQL*Plus because the GUI tool, SQL Developer, won't work.

I need to run some scripts, and I found that after starting SQL*Plus I couldn't navigate from a session to another directory. The instructions that I did find after I searched on the internet all talk about a gui interface to SQL*Plus which is no longer available on version 11. All what I get is a console window.

Right now I hacked my way into making it work for me by creating a shortcut and then changing the starting directory to the directory where the scripts are housed.

I can keep doing this, but I would like to know if there is a command that will let me know 
a) the current working directory and 
b) how to change directories

Thanks in advance,

Hugo

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try: `host pwd` and `host cd somedir`.  You can also enter just `host` to get a command prompt.

Also, `help` is your friend.

Comment: Awesome! Exactly the information that I needed :)   It worked like a charm.

For anyone else who might benefit from his answer, God's way of getting the current working directory on command line, pwd, doesn't work in windows.

for that, you do echo %CD%

So, within sql*plus, you would write
host echo %cd%

Thanks again, shoover :)

Answer (score 7):

The host command runs a subshell under unix. Thus, `cd` will change the directory in the subshell, but not for SQL*Plus itself.

Answer (score 1):

Even I had the same issue. I tried to find the solution, but I settled down for a run.sql file solution. You can try some thing like this.

```
C:\Guru>Dir
11/27/2009  10:29 AM    <DIR>          .
11/27/2009  10:29 AM    <DIR>          ..
09/02/2009  07:15 PM    <DIR>          fol
09/02/2009  08.15 PM                   run.sql
```

In run.sql specify

```
@"c:\Guru\fol\a.sql"
show error
@"c:\Guru\fol\b.sql"
show error
```

And so on. You can give the folder structure as you wish. Even you can put them into windows BATCH file and execute them in one click.